# Count clicks in Piwik and Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, matomo

I got an application running using Piwik. I've read the Piwik documentation and googled a lot but without luck.

All I want to do is, count one specific click on my website. Does anyone know, how to do that?

Comment: Try something yourself first. Then post your code and ask specific question if you get some issue. SO is not a code writing service :)

Comment: I didn't ask anyone to write code but to help me getting started since the documentation didn't help me whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the Event Tracking function in javascript ? here an explanation : http://piwik.org/docs/event-tracking/

With this you just have to add the function in your html element like this for example :

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Documentary', 'Play', 'Thrive']);"> Link </a>
```

*Documentary* is the category, *Play* the action, and *Thrive* the name of the event. The name of the event is optional.

And then you will see how many times your link has been clicked in your piwik dashboard, in Actions -> Events

I don't know if it answers to you question

Comment: Event Tracking, that was the key word - thank you so much. Wonder why I haven't found it before...